# Read from all text files in folder, check for matches and insert text file value into Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, text-files

I am attempting to work on a code which will allow me to check two lines of all my text files in a folder.

Each text file will be structured like so:

```
NS1234        <--- A random reference number on the first line
Approve       < Reject or Approve on the second line
```

At the moment the code only reads one text file which I specify the name of, however I want it to scan all .txt files.

Next, When I open my spread sheet I will have the following set-up:

```
Column A     Column
NS1234
```

I want my code to scan all text files to check for any matching reference number from column A against all the text files.

And then where a match is found insert either 'Approve' or 'Reject', where this is written on the second line of the text file, into the corresponding row in column s

Code:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim fn As Integer
    fn = FreeFile
    Open "Z:\NS\Approval\NS32D1QR.txt" For Input As fn

    Dim wholeFile As String
    wholeFile = Input(LOF(fn), #fn)

    Close #fn

    Dim splitArray
    splitArray = Split(wholeFile, vbCrLf)

    Dim lineNum As Integer
    lineNum = 2


    Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer
    intValueToFind = NS32D1QR
    For i = 1 To 500    ' Revise the 500 to include all of your values
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = intValueToFind And splitArray(lineNum - 1) = "Approve" Then
    Range("S" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Approve"
    End If

    Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please specify what is your problem? Is your code giving an error (if yes what and where), not doing what is supposed to do, or any more details of the issue you are facing!

Comment: I'm on it ;) Answer coming

Answer (score 0):

i 'm not sure about the test that you made in your loop but it seems to me that the info where on the 2 first lines so no use to loop or to use special variables there. Let me know if this work properly or not! ;)

Here is a sub to test, as it is a function you can either loop on it or use it in Excel workbook.

```
Sub test()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 2 To .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(i, "S") = Get_AorP(.Cells(i, "A"))
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Here is what you wanted to do, converted to a function :

```
    Public Function Get_AorP(ByVal Value_to_Find As String) As String
        Dim fn As Integer, _
            Txts_Folder_Path As String, _
            File_Name As String, _
            wholeFile As String, _
            splitArray() As String, _
            i As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Txts_Folder_Path = "Z:\NS\Approval\"
    File_Name = Dir(Txts_Folder_Path & "*.txt")

    While File_Name <> vbNullString
        fn = FreeFile
        Open Txts_Folder_Path & File_Name For Input As fn
            wholeFile = Input(LOF(fn), #fn)
        Close #fn
        MsgBox File_Name
        splitArray = Split(wholeFile, vbCrLf)

        If UBound(splitArray) < 2 Or LBound(splitArray) > 1 Then
            'avoid empty text files
        Else
            If InStr(1, splitArray(0), Value_to_Find) <> 0 Then
                If InStr(1, splitArray(1), "Approve") Then
                    Get_AorP = "Approve"
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    If InStr(1, splitArray(1), "Reject") Then
                        Get_AorP = "Reject"
                        Exit Function
                    Else
                        'Nothing to do
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                'not the good value
            End If
        End If
        File_Name = Dir()
    Wend

    Get_AorP = "No matches found"
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
        Get_AorP = "Error during the import." & vbCrLf & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description
    End Function
```

Comment: @R2uK thanks for your code, I have tried this and it always comes up with No Matches Found. Where abouts in the code does it check column A for the reference in the text file?

Comment: It wasn't checking in any column or anything as it is a function. Look at the edit to see how to use it in code for your specific purpose. And I added a MsgBox to display the files' names so that you can "monitor" and see if something wrong. The only part I'm not sure of, is the testing part : `If splitArray(0) <> Value_to_Find` and `If splitArray(1) <> "Approve"` All the infos are on the 2 firsts lines right?

Comment: I changed the tests, try it again and let me know!